# Stop executing code in R

Tags: r

I use data checks in my code, for example the following one:

```
if (...)
stop(paste('Warning: Weights do not sum up to 1')
```

The problem is that if the condition is true and the warning appears in the console, the code does not stop running. If hidden in a long code, one needs to scroll up always in the console output to see if a warning appeared.

Is there a way to tell R to interupt ALL code when the stop warning appears and the condition is true? Something like BREAK ?

I do not represent a reproducible example here because my code is quite long.

EDIT:

Here is a mini example:

When I execute

```
a=1+2

if (a==3)
  stop('a equals 3')


b=4

1+1
```

I would like to stop after printing

```
> a=1+2
> 
> if (a==3)
+   stop('a equals 3')
Error: a equals 3
```

but R executes everything, also the last part:

```
> a=1+2
> 
> if (a==3)
+   stop('a equals 3')
Error: a equals 3
>        
>        
> b=4
> 
> 1+1
[1] 2
```

Comment: Having "quite long" code is not an excuse to not make the effort to create a reproducible example. Not only does it help those who would like to help, many times you will figure out the solution in the process.

Comment: So, you source something like `stop("foo_error"); print(iris)` and want to avoid echoing/evaluating `print(iris)`? `stop` is intended to be used in functions and you could wrap your code in functions. E.g., `fun <- function() {stop("foo_error"); print(iris)}; fun()`.

Comment: Are you doing a "Source All" or similar?

Comment: @Pierre: See my edit above, you were right, it is maybe easier with a mini-example.

Comment: @Roland: I was not aware that stop should only be used in functions--Maybe I need a different command then outside a function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to `stop`, it only stops evaluation of the *current* expression. While I agree with [Roland's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33391619/stop-executing-code-in-r#comment54574941_33391619) to encapsulate your code into meaningful pieces via functions, a quick hack would be to wrap all your current code in curly braces. That will make it appear to the R parser as a single expression.

```
R> # without curly braces
R> x <- 1
R> y <- 2
R> if (x < y)
+   stop("x < y")
Error: x < y
R> print("hello")
[1] "hello"
R>
R> # with curly braces
R> {
+   x <- 1
+   y <- 2
+   if (x < y)
+     stop("x < y")
+   print("hello")
+ }
Error: x < y
```

Comment: Hi Joshua, thanks for your answer, your method provides me with only the error message, but the code is still fully running, we just don't see it because it is inside the function?!

Comment: @fuji2015: no, it's not running, and it's not in a function. It's in an expression, and the remainder of the expression is skipped if `stop` is called.

Comment: My mistake, I looked at the post below. Of course, there is no function at your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, it seems not to be the default behaviour of R.

So I think there is some change of the stop handler. You can try to call `options(stop=NULL)` before running your code. See [the doc](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/stop.html):

> The default behaviour (the NULL error-handler) in interactive use is
>   to return to the top level prompt or the top level browser, and in
>   non-interactive use to (effectively) call q("no", status = 1, runLast
>   = FALSE).

At least the following code worked in my case (R 3.2.1):

```
funErr <- function() {
    if (TRUE)
        stop("now")

    print("after stop")
}

funCaller <- function() {
    print("before call")

    funErr()

    print("after call")
}


print("before global")

# Also possible to uncomment the following to test the `stop()` 
# inside of `funErr()`
if(TRUE)
    stop("global error")

funCaller()
```